# AngularJS Forced reflow is a likely performance bottleneck Google Chrome developer tools timeline

Tags: angularjs, performance, google-chrome-devtools

I have a click event in web page that is taking quite a long time which is AngularJS code. Google Chrome developer tools Timeline data suggests that `Forced reflow is a likely performance bottleneck.` is the problem. I don't seem to understand where is the exact problem that i can resolve.

[image]

Comment: Well ng-animate likely causes forced redraws internally

Comment: @TJ how can i avoid this? what should i do to resolve the bottleneck?

Comment: Well usually it isn't such a performance issue and does not cause such warning for everyone. Something spooky is happening specifically with your code which is causing the problem. Maybe the reflow mentioned in warning is cased by your code itself. Sorry can't help much without debugging the code causing this...

Comment: @KashifKhan Just curious what version of angularjs you are using? I am migrating over a project from 1.3 to 1.6 and am having the same issues..